# Inserting a momentjs object in Meteor Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, momentjs

I have a simple Meteor collection and I am trying to insert a document that has a momentjs property into it. So I do:

```
docId = Col.insert({m: moment()});
```

However, when I try to get this document back with

```
doc = Col.findOne({_id: docId})
```

I get "Invalid date" for doc.m like so:

```
Object {_id: "wnHzTpHHxMSyMxmu3", m: "Invalid date"}
```

Anyone?!

Comment: MomentJS is for presentation. When storing you should store the model, not the presentation coolness that you'll use later for reasons the db shouldn't care about.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I strongly recommend storing dates as `Date` objects and using moment to format them after they are fetched. For example:

```
Posts.insert({message: 'hello', createdAt: new Date});
```

Then later when you want to display the date:

```
var date = Posts.findOne().createdAt;
moment(date).format('MMMM DD, YYYY');
```

Comment: Yeah, better approach.

Comment: This of course works, but I was hoping someone will come up with a reason for why is this happening. What objects I can and cannot insert in a Meteor collection? What is so special about momentjs?

Comment: @babbata this is happening because you can't store moment objects in a mongo collection except for the primitive standard js types. You need to store your data with something like EJSON to let you store your own types. There is a good screencast on this at https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/gZEKQxLtBzyhE8NTF

Comment: @Akshat thanks a lot for the explanation, dude. Will take a look at the screencast.

Answer (score 4):

Moments are not designed to be directly serializable.  They won't survive a round-trip to/from JSON.  The best approach would be to serialize an ISO8601 formatted date, such as with `moment().toISOString()` or `moment().format()`.  (`toISOString` is prefered, but will store at UTC instead of local+offset).

Then later, you can parse that string with `moment(theString)` and do what you want with it from there.

David's answer is also correct.  Though it will rely on whatever Metor's default mechanism is for serializing `Date` objects, as `Date` also cannot exist directly in JSON.  I don't know the specifics of Meteor - but chances are it's either storing an integer timestamp or just using `Date.toString()`.  The ISO8601 format is much better suited for JSON than either of those.

**UPDATE**

I just took a glance at the docs for Meteor, which explain that they use an invented format called "EJSON".  (You probably know this, but it's new to me.)

According to [these docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson), a `Date` is serialized as an integer timestamp:

```json
{
  "d": {"$date": 1358205756553}
}
```

So - David's answer is spot on (and should remain the accepted answer).  But also, if you are doing something other than just getting the current date/time, then you might want to use moment for that.  You can use `yourMoment.toDate()` and pass that so Meteor will treat it with the `$date` type in it's EJSON format.

Comment: Meteor's mechanism for serializing objects [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson) properly handles this case. `Date` objects are stored as `ISODate` in mongo.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I just found out about EJSON.  Interesting.  Non-standard, but interesting.

Comment: Why would you call it non-standard?  It's a meteor question and it's a meteor standard - it's well defined.  Would you call using JSON non-standard because it's not present in C?  Then why call EJSON nonstandard because it's not used in other systems?

Comment: @xaxxon - JSON is a standard, as ratified by the [ECMA standards organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecma_International), in [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).  EJSON is just some extensions made up by the authors of Meteor.  I'm not saying that's bad - but that doesn't make it a [technical standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_standard).

Comment: a "technical standard" is an arbitrary definition.  How many people does it take to make a standard?  "nonstandard" simply means not standard.  Standard does not require any particular body to recognize it - you can check the definition: used or accepted as normal or average..  ejson is 100% a standard part of meteor.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have moment objects on `find` and `findOne`, save it as a date then transform it on finding it. For example:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts', {
  transform: function (doc) {
    Object.keys(doc).forEach(field => {
      if (doc[field] instanceof Date) {
        doc[field] = moment(doc[field]);
      }
    });
    return doc;
  }
});

Posts.insert({
  title: 'Hello',
  createdAt: new Date()
});
```