# MongoDB find newest date in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I want to search the newest date in a collection. The date is formatted like this: `YYYY-MM-DD`.
For instance:

```
{ "release" : "2014-09-25", "desc" : "Test1", "status" : "ok", "_id" : "…" }
{ "release" : "2014-09-26", "desc" : "Test2", "status" : "ok", "_id" : "…" }
{ "release" : "2014-09-27", "desc" : "Test3", "status" : "ok", "_id" : "…" }
```

The result set should be:

```
{ "release" : "2014-09-27", "desc" : "Test3", "status" : "ok", "_id" : "…" }
```

Is there a special mongoDB operator for that case, or do I have to fetch all documents in the collection and make a loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are storing date as a string, first convert them to ISODate if possible.

Comment: You mean as `ISO 8601 String`? I am using `moment.js`.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937448/inserting-a-momentjs-object-in-meteor-collection

Comment: If this has sorted your problem then please accept the answer so it is helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing date as String, please change it to date object and the you could sort it using mongo sort

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

```
db.collection.find().sort( { date: -1 } ).limit(1)
```

For storing as date from moment.js see this link here: [Inserting a momentjs object in Meteor Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937448/inserting-a-momentjs-object-in-meteor-collection)